# looping function call with commit

Tags: postgresql, transactions, plpgsql

I have a plpgsql function which updates table data. I want to call this function within a loop passing the looping variable as an argument, and commit after each function call.

I tried to make another plpgsql function, but I figured out that i can't do commit in a function unlike oracle procedure.

Is there a way to do this in a regular sql editor or psql?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can, but you have to use the [dblink-extension](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dblink.html) to make an external connection to your database. A lot of overhead, will be slower, but it works. Maybe this will do for your situation.